# How to produce a hierarchical query in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table but I'm not able to write the relation to extract the tree.

Here is an example of the data:

```
LOT_ID | LOT_PRODUCED | ITEM_PRODUCED | ITEM_USED | LOT_USED | OPERATION | STEP  
------ | ------------ | ------------- | --------- | -------- | --------- | ---- 
1      | LOT_1        | ITEM_1        | null      | null     | P         | STEP_1
1      | null         | null          | ITEM_1    | LOT_1    | C         | STEP_2
5      | null         | null          | ITEM_2    | LOT_2    | C         | STEP_2
5      | LOT_2        | ITEM_2        | null      | null     | P         | STEP_8
5      | null         | null          | ITEM_2    | LOT_2    | C         | STEP_1
6      | null         | null          | ITEM_2    | LOT_7    | C         | STEP_8
```

Starting from LOT_PRODUCED = LOT_1, I'd like to have a tree with every steps linked to the step of the starting lot.

So in this example, we see that STEP_1 (step that produced LOT_1) consumes LOT_2. That lot was produced by STEP_8. This step in turn consumes LOT_7. And so on.

I think I understand the concept of START WITH and CONNECT BY but I'm not able to solve this case as the link is 'jumping' between columns. There is no defined parent and child.

If this is not solvable with a simple query, I'm open to a stored procedure.

Edit:

[Here is a drawing of the data shown above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmIJi.jpg)

So on the left there are the explanations of the links:

- lot consumed by a step
- step produces a lot

And on the right there is the links: the number on the connectors is the row number of the data shown above.

Comment: Clear as mud. Which row shows that LOT_1 consumes LOT_2? There is no row in your table to show any connection between them, either directly or by a chain of other rows. (If there is, please explain.)

Comment: It looks like you have three enumerable entities: lots, items and steps. However I don't think it is clear what the relationship is between these things - would you edit your question to indicate (roughly) what these things are. It looks like a step _produces_ an item, a step _uses_ an item, and a step _uses_ a lot. Would you clarify?

Comment: You may find a graphical representation embedded in your question helps illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT G.STEP,
  LOT_USED,
  ITEM_USED,
  LOT_PRODUCED,
  ITEM_PRODUCED
FROM GENEALOGY G
  START WITH G.STEP      = 'STEP01'
  CONNECT BY LOTPRODUCED = PRIOR LOTUSED
AND ITEMPRODUCED         = PRIOR ITEMUSED
ORDER BY G.STEP
```

But this only returns the first level of consumptions:
from the starting step, I get consumed lots and then for each of these lots, I get the step that produced it. I also get the lot produced by the starting step if any.

To link with my example data, I get (starting from STEP_1):

```
STEP   | LOT_USED | ITEM_USED | LOT_PRODUCED | ITEM_PRODUCED
-------|----------|-----------|--------------|---------------
STEP_1 | LOT_2    | ITEM_2    |              |
STEP_1 |          |           | LOT_1        | ITEM_1
STEP_8 |          |           | LOT_2        | ITEM_2
```

I then changed the query to include the existing part as a sub-query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.STEP,
  LOTUSED,
  ITEMUSED,
  LOTPRODUCED,
  ITEMPRODUCED
FROM GENEALOGY H
  START WITH H.STEP IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT G.STEP
     FROM GENEALOGY G
       START WITH G.STEP = 'STEP_1'
       CONNECT BY LOTPRODUCED = PRIOR LOTUSED
     AND ITEMPRODUCED         = PRIOR ITEMUSED
    )
  CONNECT BY LOTPRODUCED = PRIOR LOTUSED
AND ITEMPRODUCED         = PRIOR ITEMUSED
ORDER BY H.STEP
```

I then get 2 levels of consumptions.

To link with my example data, I get (starting from STEP_1):

```
STEP   | LOT_USED | ITEM_USED | LOT_PRODUCED | ITEM_PRODUCED
-------|----------|-----------|--------------|---------------
STEP_1 | LOT_2    | ITEM_2    |              |
STEP_1 |          |           | LOT_1        | ITEM_1
STEP_8 |          |           | LOT_2        | ITEM_2
STEP_8 | LOT_7    | ITEM_2    |              |
```

So I can get as many level of consumptions as CONNECT BY present in the query.
But I of course would like to get the full tree.
I don't know the number of levels in advance and even if I knew it was for example 30, my query would be "huge" for no reason.

Does someone has an idea to help me build a more simple query for my problem?
Maybe work with the P (produce) and C (consume) OPERATION field and the LOT_ID?